# Why is my span stripped out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to remove any occurense of e\E in the div:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" class="example">
  Some Example text
  <span class="abe">
    <span class="abe">
      this is an inner text of the span
    </span>
    text in the span
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
span{color:blue;}​
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text().replace(/e|E/g, '')); // removes each e\E in the text
});​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/2/)

For some reason my span get stripped out and only it's inner text remains.
WHY? and how can I fix it?

---

**Update:**

I know `text` gives only the text, I used it becuase I don't want to change the tags attributes. When I used `.html` it changed `<span id="abe">` to `<span id="ab">`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/5/)**

Comment: because the call to inner $this.text() returns all the text without html elements, then assigning it back to $this would yield no elements http://jsfiddle.net/Yue67/

Comment: using `.html()` also resulting same http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/3/

Comment: @tusar. But it mess with the tag itself, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/4/) out. I updated my answer with that fiddle.

Comment: @tusar I'm using chrome and as far as I see it, the `<span>` is preserved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by others, `text()` replaces the contents of the element or elements with plain text. You need to iterate over the text nodes within the element and replace characters within their content using the `data` or `nodeValue` property of each text node. Here's how to do that with jQuery (using code adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery/4399718#4399718)). 'e' and 'E' characters are replaced with '[X]' for clarity but it's trivial to change.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TqBLu/

Code:

```
$("#container").find(":not(iframe)").andSelf().contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        this.data = this.data.replace(/e/ig, "[X]");
    }
});
```

Here's a version without jQuery for people like me who don't generally use it:

```
function replaceInTextNodes(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(/e/ig, "[X]");
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
            replaceInTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}

replaceInTextNodes(document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: I think the `not(iframe)` should be `not(span)`. Also I dont understand `nodeType` would you like to explain a bit ?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see your answer. in the meanwhile I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9905231/601179) with recursion. looks like I did too much work.

Comment: @tusar: The `:not(iframe)` bit is there to avoid `contents()` attempting to traverse iframe documents. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11275. `not(span)` would prevent traversal of text nodes within spans, which is not what is required. As to `nodeType`, that's a standard property of all DOM nodes, and text nodes have a `nodeType` of 3 (also available as `Node.TEXT_NODE`, but the node constants are not supported in older IE). See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247

Comment: @gdoron: Our answers use essentially the same approach. It's the best way.

Comment: @gdoron: The fastest would be based on plain DOM methods. I may add that to my answer.

Comment: The [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/ways-to-find-text-nodes). Plain javascript is the winner.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the textContent or innerText (which is what `text()` does) removes all tags from the element.

Aside from that, you were only getting the text in the first place (minus tags), and putting it back in. You wiped out the span in two different ways.

Comment: Check my update, `.html` gives my the tag, so `<span id="abe">` becomes `<span id="ab">`. I don't want to touch the tags, only, it's content. any ideas?

Comment: Loop through child nodes. If a node is a tag, recurse. If it's a text node, replace.

Comment: You may be interested with the result. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903668/why-is-my-span-stripped-out#comment12661843_9904107) comment. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with negative lookahead `(?! ...)`: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqkud/1/
In this way I apply a replacement of `e` character only if it's not contained in angular brackets (as a substring of the tagname or attribute name/value)

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/(?!.*<.*[e]*.*>.*)e*/gi, ''));
});
```

Comment: [The pony he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - What if the HTML contains unescaped `<` or `>` that should be escaped?

Comment: good point kolink: of course it's a workaround and its usage depends on what kind of markup has to be handled with that regexp.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend a regex solution: it's unreliable, slow and overcomplicated, and a simple, reliable solution exists: iterate over the text nodes.

Comment: @TimDown. Actually your first answer is the slowest... **:)** [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9905231/601179) (with jQuery) is the fastest. [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/ways-to-find-text-nodes). your's update with plain javascript is faster then jQuery(obviously).

Comment: @gdoron: Fair enough, that's one reason not to use a regex gone, only leaving about another 99 :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it with recursion:

**Javascript:**

```
function change(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        node.data = node.data.replace(/e|E/g, '');
    }
    else {
        $(node).contents().each(function() {
            change(this);
        });
    }
}

$('div').contents().each(function() {
    change(this);
});
```

**Based on this `HTML`:**

```
<div class="example">Some Example text  
    <span class="abe">
        <span class="abe"> this is an inner text of the span </span>  text in the span 
    </span>
</div>
<div class="example">Some more Example text</div>​        
​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/8/)